# Primefaces dynamic columns, programmatically

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm in the process of rewriting a (very) big and old Richfaces application using Primefaces. I now have a situation where I get two lists, one with column names and one with objects that should be represented as rows.

The object looks like this:

```
public class AVeryGenericThingThatIDoNotLike {
    Object[] values;
    //Other parameters that I dont care about
}
```

When I should display this I want it to map values[0] to the first column, values[1] to the second and so forth.

I have looked at the primefaces showcase and there is an example of dynamic columns but I have tried that and I can not get it to work when I do not know what columns that can exist. The reason that I do not know this is that the columns are decided from a database that holds a row saying what columns that should exist and this can change, so I can not build a class to have all the columns available like in the showcase example.

Can anyone give me any pointers here? I've been stuck on this for a few days and I really need help.

EDIT: Now it is kinda working with the solution from Laabidi Raissi. My problem now is that for some columns I want to have buttons being rendered and command links. With this approach I am only able to get strings and if I try to return objects like CommandButtons it will just print a java object hash.

Comment: Does each row of a table have a different size of "values"?

Comment: no, all rows have the same amount of values.

Comment: How exactly is the example in PF showcase insufficient? Just feed the value of `<p:columns>` with a dynamic list? Or are you looking at the wrong showcase example or perhaps overcomplicating things?

Comment: Coming back to `<p:columns>`, you may find [those examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+%22%3Cp%3Acolumns%3E%22) helpful to get some insights.

Comment: @BalusC, please have a look at the edit in the main question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using JSF2, then I think this solution may work for you. First, in your managed bean, you build your list of columns (dynamically) from DB, and then:

```
<p:columns value="#{yourManagedBean.listOfColumnsFromDB}"  var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex">  
  <f:facet name="header"> #{column}</f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{yourManagedBean.values[colIndex]}" />
</p:columns>
```

EDIT: Base on your comment, I think adding `commandbutton` or `outputlink` is very obvious (instead of the `outputText`):

```
<h:commandButton value="#{yourManagedBean.values[colIndex]}" action="#{yourManagedBean.someActionThatTakesAParam(colIndex)}" rendered="#{colIndex == 4}"/>
```

Supposing you want commandButton in column 5.

Is that what you are looking for ?

Hope this helps

Comment: @Laabodo Raissi, please have a look at the edit in the main question

Comment: please see my edited answer. PS: I like the way you wrote my name

Comment: sorry for the name :P Your solution would work if all columns where command buttons or links. The problem is that it is mixed, some ordinary text, some buttons and some links =/

Comment: then, you can work with rendered attribute and colIndex value, see updated answer

Comment: that might be able to work! will update with the result when it is tested!

Comment: are you postive that it is possible to send parameters like you suggested? I tried to use this in the rendered attrib: #{myBean.isColumnTextField(colIndex)} but it gives me parse error =/

Comment: ah, aren't you using EL 2.2 ? If not, then try to use <f:param>

Comment: I ended up using a variation of your suggestion with the rendered attribute. Thank you for your help!