# Primefaces- Dynamic generation of XML tags from Backing bean

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

My questions similar to [this](http://kevindoran1.blogspot.com/2012/02/dynamic-primefaces-menus-menu-menubar.html).

I am creating a user interface for some tables in the Database.The client wants the UI to be dynamic,like there will be `selectonemenu` where ,if I select an item the datatable should bring the tabble as it is fro mthe DB and displayed it in the datatable.

I have typical requirement where I need to generate the `<p:datatable>` dynamically and also the columns
The columns is also going to have different type of datatypes such as `inputtext`,`selectonemenu` and `what not.`
All I am trying to do here is generate the each every tag inside the `datatable` as a dynamic one which included the data table too.

Is there any classed available in primfaces to generate the XML tags from the backing bean ?
Any sugggestions from you will be really helpful to resolve this issue.

Comment: Whats is in the db-tables, normal entities? What is the total number of db-tables you need to show?

Comment: Those are normal tables ,the number of tables would come arund 14 to 15..

Comment: If no "magic" suggestion comes up you can always create the 15 tables and make sure only the one selected in the selectonemenu has rendered="true". Each table could be like this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml if the users want to customize the columns. If it suits your needs I would'nt be afraid of this solution as it would be rather simple, and you would have to find a very very generic solution to avoid having a bit of code for every column. You can even reverse engineer the db-tables with for example netbeans and copy/paste everything

Comment: May be you want somthing like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833764/primefaces-dynamic-columns-programatically (example http://www.mastertheboss.com/primefaces/datatables-with-primefaces ) Or you can use this approach http://www.wobblycogs.co.uk/index.php/computing/jee/77-dynamic-datatable-with-jsf-20