# Primefaces dynamic datatable with json dataset of rows and columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to create datatable on the basis of two sets of data. One dataset contains header information and other dataset contains data inside it.
both of the dataset are in the form of json array.
**Rows dataset:**

```
[
  {
    "fname": "Umair",
    "lname": "Baig"
  },
  {
    "fname": "Ali",
    "lname": "Hassan"
  }

]
```

**Columns dataset:**

```
[
  {
    "header_alias": "fname",
    "label": "First Name"
  },
  {
    "header_alias": "lname",
    "label": "Last Name"
  }

]
```

Both Row and columns datasets can vary and i have multiple column and rows datasets. Variation in rows and columns dataset is. It can have more than two headers and same goes with row.
I can not create one single Pojo class to handle this type of dataset. I need to generate dynamic columns and dynamic rows.
Please have a look into the code that i have created so far.
I need to stick with primefaces datatable to solve it. I can not move to some other fancy component suite like prime ui datatable handles it very easily.
**Classes that i am using of primefaces/jsf:**

```
org.primefaces.component.column.Column
org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable
javax.faces.component.UIOutput

List<Column> columnList = new ArrayList<Column>();
        for (int i = 0; i < uiColumns.size(); i++) {
            final String header = uiColumns.get(i).getHeader().replace("_", " ").toUpperCase();
            Column column = new Column();
            column.setHeaderText(header);
            columnList.add(column);
        }

// Columns component added in datatable
this.getMyDataTable().getChildren().addAll(columnList);
```

This problem i am facing right now is when i try append rows data it basically concat all in one column.

```
UIOutput output = new UIOutput();
String value = this.rowsdata.get(i);
// value contains the cell value which will be added as a output Text
output.setValue(value);
uiComponentList.add(output);

List<UIComponent> components =  columnList.get(i).getChildren();
// i index is for iteration over columns of datatable
components.addAll(uiComponentList);
```

[image]

As you can see in the Picture. **UmairAli** is appended in first column. it should be like **Umair** in 1st row and **Ali** in 2nd row.

Comment: Your title is bad, it is just a summary of tags. and why not use the normal PF dynamic `p:columns`???

Comment: What about the datatable var="car" value="#{dtColumnsView.cars}". as i mentioned i can not create pojo classes because the property are altogether dynamic both in column headers and rows.

Comment: You don't need a pojo, you need a 'service' that uses the json. Sort of like you do now but without the need for all this low-level jsf.

Comment: Can you pls share an example?

Comment: No, sorry, technically it is not different from using data from hashmaps or a dynamic database result set  the dynamic columns example in the primefaces showcase. Just use the column index as a mapping key

Comment: but I found a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833764/primefaces-dynamic-columns-programmatically

Comment: Let me try the solution you shared. I would probably remove this question after that.

Comment: No, please don't. if it works, it will most likely be marked as duplicate but it might serve as an entrypoint for others doing searches (you did not find the other one either ;-))

Comment: @Kukeltje, Ok i got your idea then what about the list that we need to put in <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{dtColumnsView.cars}"> i dont want to create cars list in my pojo. Any idea?

Comment: The `value` can point to your array(List), the `var` can be any name (e.g. `myVar` and in the column tag use `myVar[0]` and `myVar[1]` or do it dynamically in a `p:columns` tag either using the colIndex or the explicit var...

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje, i have solved the problem.